# Regular Expression, allow whitespace in between text

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have the following validation code wherein it filters only alpha numeric + white space text... But upon testing two alpha numeric words with whitespace, it fails...

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphaNumeric", function(value, element) {
    $(element).val(value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''));
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(value);
}, " AlphaNumeric Only!");
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/.test("foo bar");` yields `true` for me. Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net demo showing the issue?

Comment: it it because of this code? $(element).val(value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''));

Comment: You're not testing the value you're putting in the element, is that intentional? E.g., by the time you apply the regex, `value` still can have leading and trailing whitespace (but even so, your test doesn't care, so I'm still not seeing the problem as described).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you change the input value but its not the value you are checking on your validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphaNumeric", function(value, element) {
    value = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    $(element).val(value); //element.value = value
    return /^(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *)+)$/.test(value);
}, " AlphaNumeric Only!");
```

I don´t know of the replacement/trim method should be in a validation rule. But this should work.

Comment: While true (and in fact, I commented on it), this doesn't fit his problem description.